# recursively list files that contain m of n regex

Tags: regex, bash, search, awk, grep

I have a directory with quite some files. I have `n` search patterns and would like to list all files that match `m` of those.

Example: From the files below, list the ones that contain at least *two* of `str1`, `str2`, `str3` and `str4`.

```sh
$ ls -l dir/
total 16
-rw-r--r--. 1 me me 10 Jun 22 14:22 a
-rw-r--r--. 1 me me  5 Jun 22 14:22 b
-rw-r--r--. 1 me me 10 Jun 22 14:22 c
-rw-r--r--. 1 me me  9 Jun 22 14:22 d
-rw-r--r--. 1 me me 10 Jun 22 14:22 e
$ cat dir/a
str1
str2
$ cat dir/b
str2
$ cat dir/c
str2
str3
$ cat dir/d
str
str4
$ cat dir/e
str2
str4
```

I managed to achieve this with a rather ugly `for` loop on `find` results that spawns `n` `grep` processes for each file, which obviously is super inefficient and would take ages on directories with a lot of files:

```sh
for f in $(find dir/ -type f); do
  c=0
  grep -qs 'str1' $f && let c++
  grep -qs 'str2' $f && let c++
  grep -qs 'str3' $f && let c++
  grep -qs 'str4' $f && let c++
  [[ $c -ge 2 ]] && echo $f
done
```

I am quite sure I could achieve this in a far better performing way, but I am not sure how to tackle it. From what I understand from the man page (i.e. on `-e` and `-m`) this is not possible with `grep` alone.

What would be the right tool to use? Is this possible with `awk`?

Bonus: By using `find` I can define the files to search more precisely (i.e. `-prune` certain sub directories or only search files with `-iname '*.txt'`), which I would like to do with other solutions, too.

---

## UPDATE

Some statistics about the performance of different implementations below.

---

#### `find` + `awk`

(Script from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62516128/2656118) answer)

```
real    0m0,006s
user    0m0,002s
sys     0m0,004s
```

---

#### `python`

(I'm a `python` noob, please advise if this could be optimized):

```py
import os

patterns = []
patterns = ["str1", "str2", "str3", "str4"]

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("dir"):
    for file in files:
        c = int(0)
        filepath = os.path.join(root, file)
        with open(filepath, 'r') as input:
            for pattern in patterns:
                for line in input:
                    if pattern in line:
                        c += 1
                        break
        if ( c >= 2 ):
            print(filepath)
```

```
real    0m0,025s
user    0m0,019s
sys     0m0,006s
```

---

#### `c++`

(Script from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62519890/2656118) answer)

```
real    0m0,002s
user    0m0,001s
sys     0m0,001s
```

Comment: Are the timing results you posted third-run timings to remove cache-ing impact from the results? I assume whether a script takes 0.002s or 0.006s doesn't matter to you as they're both in the blin of an eye range - if you have larger files where performance would matter could you test the timing using those? Also, you're comparing a C++ program that has hard-coded `str1`, etc. against an awk program that reads the values from a file - that's obviously not apples to apples comparison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the programming language doesn't matter as much as the performance, here's a version in C++. I haven't compared it with `awk` myself though.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main() {
    const fs::path dir = "dir";
    std::vector<std::string_view> strs{   // or: std::array<std::string_view, 4>
        "str1",
        "str2",
        "str3",
        "str4",
    };

    std::string line;
    int count;     // matches in a file
    size_t strsco; // number of strings to check in strs

    // a lambda to find a match on a line
    auto matcher = [&](const fs::directory_entry& de) {
        for(size_t idx = 0; idx < strsco; ++idx) {
            if(line.find(strs[idx]) != std::string::npos) {
                // a match was found

                if(++count >= 2) {
                    std::cout << de.path() << '\n';
                    // or the below if the quotation marks surrounding the path are
                    // unwanted:
                    // std::cout << de.path().native() << '\n';
                    return false;
                }

                // swap the found string_view with the last in the vector
                // to remove it from future matches in this file.
                --strsco;
                std::swap(strs[idx], strs[strsco]);
            }
        }
        return true;
    };

    // do a "find dir -type f"
    for(const fs::directory_entry& de : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(dir)) {
        if(de.is_regular_file()) { // -type f

            // open the found file
            if(std::ifstream file(de.path()); file) {
                // reset counters
                count = 0;
                strsco = strs.size();
                // read line by line until the file stream is depleated or matcher()
                // returns false
                while(std::getline(file, line) && matcher(de));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Save it to `prog.cpp` and compile like this (if you have `g++`):

```
g++ -std=c++17 -O3 -o prog prog.cpp
```

If you use another compiler, be sure to turn on optimization for speed and that it requires C++17.

Comment: Wow, this is really extremly fast! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat reg.txt
str1
str2
str3
str4
```

```
$ cat prog.awk
# reads regexps from the first input file
# parameterized by `m'
# requires gawk or mawk for `nextfile'
FNR == NR {
  reg[NR] = $0
  next
}
FNR == 1 {
  for (i in reg)
    tst[i]
  cnt = 0
}
{
  for (i in tst) {
    if ($0 ~ reg[i]) {
      if (++cnt == m) {
        print FILENAME
        nextfile
      }
      delete tst[i]
    }
  }
}
```

```
$ find dir -type f -exec awk -v m=2 -f prog.awk reg.txt {} +
dir/a
dir/c
```

Comment: This works like a charm, thank you. I am still struggling with `awk` syntax. Would you mind explaining the script?

Comment: @David explaining the syntax would be a waste of time, as it's all written in the manual.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an option using `awk` since you tagged it with that too:

```
find dir -type f -exec \
awk '/str1|str2|str3|str4/{c++} END{if(c>=2) print FILENAME;}' {} \;
```

It will however count duplicates, so a file containing

```
str1
str1
```

will be listed.

Comment: Thank you. Aside from the problem with multiple occurrences of the same pattern on my system it is also somehow slower than the other solution (`real 0m0,024s
user 0m0,009s
sys 0m0,009s` vs `real 0m0,006s
user 0m0,001s
sys 0m0,004s`).

Comment: @David You're welcome! The speed diff is odd, but I wouldn't use `awk` at all when speed is important :-)

Comment: Okay, what would be a smarter way, then? Implementing both the file list generation and pattern matching completely in a programming language like python/perl/go/php?

Comment: @David For speed, I'd go with C++ and let the program do both the `find` and pattern matching internally - but that requires a little more than a one-liner. `perl` and `python` are usually good enough though. I don't know `go` so I can't speak for that. I would not use `php` for this ever.

Comment: Don't know about perl, but a solution using python would be way slower than an awk one.

Comment: @oguzismail If you also let python do the `find` internally so that there's one program doing the whole thing?

Comment: Not sure. If you give it a try and post here I'll indeed upvote though

Comment: @oguzismail Thanks :-) It would be a bit confusing to future readers though and I'll probably get downvoted for bringing in languages unrelated to the question.

Comment: See updated question. I would not assume this is unrelated since the question's focus is on how to achieve the search *the most performant way*.

Comment: @David Ok, I added a separate answer for  a C++ version. I have no idea how it performs agains anything else since I haven't measured it.

Comment: @TedLyngmo awk is usually at least as fast as C for text manipulation. In this case you're calling awk once per file individually instead of once for multiple files so that would slow things down.

Comment: @EdMorton "_at least_" is a bit of a stretch, isn't it? `gawk` is written in C.

Comment: No, it's not a stretch at all. The reason awk scripts are usually at least as fast as C programs for text manipulation is that the awk interpreter is highly optimized to do the things you need to do to manipulate text (read a line, split it into fields, set variables, compare line to a regexp, compare to a string, etc., etc.) while the typical C program isn't.

Comment: @EdMorton Ok, it was ~25 years since I did much awk scripting so I haven't compared them in a very long time. Back then I was always able to make the C programs faster though :-)

Comment: You **can** make a C program faster, but it takes more effort in code+complexity than is typically worthwhile just to manipulate text and so it's not the way people typically/intuitively write such C programs - hence awk is usually at least as fast...

Comment: FWIW google tells me that someone actually went to the trouble of implementing the same task in multiple languages and posted the timing results at https://brenocon.com/blog/2009/09/dont-mawk-awk-the-fastest-and-most-elegant-big-data-munging-language/. It is just 1 task of course (and gawk is **much** faster these days than it was back then).

Comment: @EdMorton Cool. That's impressive. I noticed that they also used an old C++ version when making the test (I'm always using C++ nowadays) and it's become a lot easier to do things faster in C++ too.

Comment: Somewhere, someone should have a site with timing stats of several languages for several tasks that'd be very interesting to see. They could take the code from http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Rosetta_Code, for example, and add the timings for each tool/language for each task. I'm not volunteering of course :-).

Comment: @EdMorton I pass on that one too :-)